# Is there a way to hide data in the bar of a script that has been added to a chart?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have attached an image as I have a script that is number a number of things but yet burying data that is useful (SMA values) that really should be in the front.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKxqi.png)

So far haven't been able to find a way to do this, and who knows if it can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course. There is a parameter in the chart settings - Indicator arguments.
[image]

Comment: AWESOME!!! But can that be scripted? Or is that one of those things that cant me?

Comment: There is no such possibility.

Comment: Oh well. Thanks, AnyDozer!!! YOU ROCK!!!!